# How can I setup NoMachines on my Linux Vps

Tags: gui, remote-desktop, nx

We'll, I basically just wanna connect to my Linux Vps via a GUI and I'v done some research on the following and I think NoMachines can get this done, However I'v Installed the Windows Client of Nomachines on my windows xp machine and tried to login but to vain.

The stats of my server are : There Is no GUI (like Gnome) Installed on my ubuntu Vps I can Access my server via SFTP but not via GUI as my host says they don't have a GUI Installed.

My Questions are : How can I install a gui to my server? Can I install a GUI on my server via SFTP? Can someone tell me the procedure to run Nomachines?

If someone has a different service they'd wanna recommend me to connect to my vps then feel free, I just wanna get the job done.

this Is precisely what I want to do : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgfuOYEmCJs&feature=related

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To install a gui on your server, you're best following this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI. That will get a GUI on your system.

The next step is to get remote desktop software. NoMachines looks like a proprietary implementation of NX technology (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology). There is an open source implementationm called FreeNX which works on Ubuntu and the Wiki has a tutorial for setting it up: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX. There is also a free implementation created by Google, but it seems less feature complete at the moment.

There are also a couple of other Remote Desktop protocols that you could have a look at such as VNC. I've used it in the past for this style of thing and it's worked well. There's more info about it on the Wiki (search it for VNC, I can only post 2 links per comment here).

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH access to the server and you have administrator privileges, the following steps should work to get NoMachine up and running:

1. Visit http://www.nomachine.com/download.php
2. Click "NX Free Edition for Linux"
3. Click "NX Free Edition for Linux DEB i386" (or amd64, if it's a 64-bit VPS)
4. Download all three packages (client, node, server). That'll give you 3 .deb files.
5. Upload these .deb files to your server with sftp
6. Connect to your server over SSH, e.g. with [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) on Windows
7. Run the following commands in your SSH session:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i nxclient_3.5.0-7_i386.deb
   sudo dpkg -i nxnode_3.5.0-3_i386.deb
   sudo dpkg -i nxserver_3.5.0-4_i386.deb
   ```

   (assuming those are the names of the .deps you uploaded)
8. Now try connecting to the server with nxclient from your local machine.

Comment: okay, how can I run the codes in the SSH session? do you mean the command prompt? and will this work with no gui installed? (like gnome/kde) ?

Comment: I ran it in the bitwise xterm command prompt and there seems to be activity there but when I try to login via the client app It says cannot login using my username, also guest login isn't allowed.

Comment: One thing you might need to do on the server side: "sudo service nxserver start".  (That should happen automatically, so it shouldn't be necessary, but it will at least confirm that the software is correctly installed & running.)

Comment: One other thing I realized -- I believe you'll still need to install some sort of GUI (like Gnome/kde/XFCE) in order for NoMachine (or any solution suggested here) to have anything that it can show you. [edit: ah yes, that's the first part of bobbo's answer here. his link there looks useful for that.]

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at X2Go. It's also based on Nomachines NX libraries, like FreeNX, NeatX and Nomachines own NX Server. But unlike the other products, the server and clients are not compatible. They've made quite a few changes. The most important one, in my opinion, is that they use PulseAudio for audio integration. This means you can use VoIP over the network, which is not possible with FreeNX, NeatX or Nomachine NX Server.